# Cocos2d: How to find radius of a sprite without using Box2d?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, game-engine

I have a circular shaped sprite. And I don't want to use Box2d physics mechanism i.e creating body and getting the radius.

Is there any mechanism in cocos2d to detect that a sprite is circular in shape and from that we can get the radius of the sprite programmatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply create your CCSprite without setting frame width and size but rather, just using the name of the image file, can't you simply just get the CCSprite's frame.bound ?

Given that your sprite is circular in shape (perfect circle I assume), then your circle's radius is essentially your box's width or height (again, I assume a perfect circle).

Comment: I am adding sprite with the following line:
hole1=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"circle.png"];
How to get its frame.bound?

Comment: ```[yoursprite boundingBox]``` or ```[yoursprite contentSize]```